# Exception in server by android retrofit

Tags: c#, android

I'm trying to throw an exception on my server so that my application on Android gets this exception and shows it, I inquired about this service at the postman, the answer I can get, was the message I send from the server "the code is not found in bd. " but in the application only the error "An error has occurred" is displayed.

this is the service and the throw:

```
 internal TDDC InfoTD()
    {
        throw new Exception("the code is not found in bd");
    }
```

this is the postman

```
{
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "the code is not found in bd",
"ExceptionType": "System.Exception",
```

And in android

```
 String errorResponse = response.errorBody().string();
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(errorResponse);
                    if (object.has("Message"))
                        message = String.valueOf(object.get("Message"));
```

¿ how i can get the message in "ExceptionMEssage" in android application ?, in this I use Retrofit 2

Comment: You need to parse response/errorbody if it's not serialize.

Comment: I use that but it not get the ExceptionMessage                               `String errorResponse = response.errorBody().string();
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(errorResponse);
                        if (object.has("Message"))
                            message = String.valueOf(object.get("Message")); `

Comment: Its more like suggestion, try to add break points and see where its failing.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bad practice to implemt or parse network error responses on your each service call.
Instead you can centralize a catch or network error like this.

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()  
        .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request();
                okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(request);

                // check your network responses here
                if (response.code() == 500) {
                    startActivity(
                            new Intent(
                                    ErrorHandlingActivity.this,
                                    ServerIsBrokenActivity.class
                            )
                    );

                    return response;
                }

                return response;
            }
        })
        .build();
```